# Actualizar clase de menú siguiendo id de secciones

Tags: javascript, html

Con que trozo de codigo js o utilidad de jquery puedo ir actualizando la clase active de mi menu al ir haciendo scroll a travez de las secciones.
Se que tiene que ver con los ids pero no encuentro la manera.
Al ir pasando por la secciones se identifiquen el id y se actualice la clase en el menu.

```css
nav {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    }
    div {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    div p {
        padding: 150px;
    }
    .active {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="active">Inicio</a>
    <a href="#">Acerca</a>
    <a href="#">Productos</a>
    <a href="#">Servicios</a>
    <a href="#">Contacto</a>
</nav>

<div id="inicio" style="background-color: black">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi aspernatur vero impedit minus in earum inventore numquam, commodi dignissimos. Corrupti odit delectus tempora eligendi asperiores vero dolor pariatur adipisci enim!</p>
</div>
<div id="acerca" style="background-color: saddlebrown">
    <p>Quidem placeat itaque sunt porro possimus eveniet vitae laborum rem ipsum nobis architecto culpa unde totam aperiam, quod, voluptates illum delectus quo facere incidunt doloremque. Provident voluptatem illo delectus soluta!</p>
</div>
<div id="productos" style="background-color: red">
    <p>Enim quisquam est, fugit modi culpa dicta minus corporis omnis natus! Commodi recusandae consectetur a molestiae, libero ratione et aspernatur consequatur autem obcaecati fugiat, magni nesciunt voluptas sapiente iusto dolorum!</p>
</div>
<div id="servicios" style="background-color: orange">
    <p>Repellat, enim? Possimus deleniti atque odio vel cumque similique eaque doloremque sapiente modi commodi, deserunt soluta dolore! Qui laudantium aliquid tempora repellendus nisi excepturi esse maxime, laboriosam quis, mollitia voluptatum.</p>
</div>
<div id="contacto" style="background-color: pik">
    <p>Numquam cum hic ducimus, debitis sunt, obcaecati repellendus corrupti, qui expedita ab commodi a esse molestias quo! Sequi ad quod quos illo dolorem, autem impedit doloremque libero alias quisquam nihil.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El evento se realiza cuando haces scroll en el window. En dicha función se coge el scroll actual y las alturas de los elementos de la navegación, luego se comprueba 1 a 1 y se muestra active la más baja de todas.

También tiene un comprobador de si le has puesto bien el enlace (si solo has puesto # se lo saltará ya que da un error si solo seleccionas #)

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll=$(window).scrollTop();
  var alturas=new Array();
  $("nav a").each(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("href");
    if(id=="#"){
      alturas.push($(document).height());
    }
    else{
      alturas.push($(id).offset().top);
    }
  });
  for(i=0;i<alturas.length;i++){
    if(alturas[i]<scroll){
      $("nav a").removeClass("active");
      $("nav a").eq(i).addClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    }
    div {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    div p {
        padding: 150px;
    }
    .active {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <a href="#inicio" class="active">Inicio</a>
    <a href="#acerca">Acerca</a>
    <a href="#productos">Productos</a>
    <a href="#">Servicios</a>
    <a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
</nav>

<div id="inicio" style="background-color: black">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi aspernatur vero impedit minus in earum inventore numquam, commodi dignissimos. Corrupti odit delectus tempora eligendi asperiores vero dolor pariatur adipisci enim!</p>
</div>
<div id="acerca" style="background-color: saddlebrown">
    <p>Quidem placeat itaque sunt porro possimus eveniet vitae laborum rem ipsum nobis architecto culpa unde totam aperiam, quod, voluptates illum delectus quo facere incidunt doloremque. Provident voluptatem illo delectus soluta!</p>
</div>
<div id="productos" style="background-color: red">
    <p>Enim quisquam est, fugit modi culpa dicta minus corporis omnis natus! Commodi recusandae consectetur a molestiae, libero ratione et aspernatur consequatur autem obcaecati fugiat, magni nesciunt voluptas sapiente iusto dolorum!</p>
</div>
<div id="servicios" style="background-color: orange">
    <p>Repellat, enim? Possimus deleniti atque odio vel cumque similique eaque doloremque sapiente modi commodi, deserunt soluta dolore! Qui laudantium aliquid tempora repellendus nisi excepturi esse maxime, laboriosam quis, mollitia voluptatum.</p>
</div>
<div id="contacto" style="background-color: pik">
    <p>Numquam cum hic ducimus, debitis sunt, obcaecati repellendus corrupti, qui expedita ab commodi a esse molestias quo! Sequi ad quod quos illo dolorem, autem impedit doloremque libero alias quisquam nihil.</p>
</div>
```